# How to use select2 in Jquery Dynamic Input Field?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I am using dynamic input field using this plugin
https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/duplicate-resort-rows-dynamic.html and for Contact Address i am using select2.Everything is working fine expect When i try to add more input field.Everything is coming empty expect contact address select2 box.and i cannot select either
[image]

This is when i try to add more input field in edit form.All Contact Name and Contact phone and email are coming empty except contact_address field and i cannot select address to .

[image]

This is my html look like

```
   @foreach($contacts as $key => $contact)
              
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="contact_name[]" value="{{ $contact->contact_name ?? null}}"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('Contact Name') }}">
               </td>
               <td>
                <input type="text" name="contact_phone[]"  value="{{ $contact->contact_phone ?? null }}"
                           class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('Contact Phone') }}">
                
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input type="text" name="contact_email[]"  value="{{ $contact->contact_email ?? null  }}"class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('Contact Email') }}">
                </td>
                <td>
               
                    <select name="contact_address[]" data-selected="{{ old('contact_address',  $contact->contact_address ?? null) }}"
                            class="contact_address form-control" >
                     @foreach($addresses as $address)
                        <option value="{{$address->id}}" @if($address->id==$contact->contact_address) selected @endif>{{$address->name}},{{$address->district}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                
            </td>
                <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-remove >
                    <i class="ni ni-fat-delete"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-add>
                    <i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i>
                </button>

            </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

My Script file look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr select[name='contact_address[]']").select2({

        theme: "classic",
        allowClear: true,
        cache: true,
    });


});
```

Comment: I believe that you need to destroy and readd select 2 ->select2("destroy") and after that ->select2() , you can try first without destroying and ofcourse this should be in clone function (when you press the add button).

Comment: How and where should i write ? please help .
i am struck for 4 days

Comment: you have a function that clone all the input when you press the + button inside this function you need first to destroy the select2, then clone it  and after that reapply select2(), can you please post the function that create the new row so i can tell you exactly where  to do it.

Comment: as per the link in your post you can add 6. Callback functions. inside this you need to destroy select2() using beforeAdd callback and reinitiate select2() using afterAdd callback.

Comment: I haven't looked it up but I also use the select2 library on a project. The cache setting is defaulted to false. You have set it to true. Couldn't that be the reason of your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $(".select2").select2();

    $('.select_all').on("select2:select", function (e) { 
        var data = e.params.data.text;
        if(data=='All'){
        $(".select_all > option").prop("selected","selected");
        $(".select_all").trigger("change");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('table[data-dynamicrows]').dynamicrows({
    beforeAdd: function($row) {
     
      $row.find('select.contact_address').select2("destroy");
    },
    afterAdd: function($row) {
      $row.find('select.contact_address').select2();
    }
  });
});
```